# jQuery - replace function

Tags: jquery, replace

How do i make a jQuery code that replaces only text in a .HTML document and not the html-tags.

Lets say that i want to replace all "b" characters to "c" in the html code. Then i don't want that the html code is replaced.

```
<b>bbbbb</b>
```

I mean that when replacing it should be only:

```
<b>ccccc</b>
```

So that the b in the html code isn't replaced.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you read the (essential) warning [against regex parsing of html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (replaces `a` with `z` everywhere inside an element with `id="main"`)

```
$('#main, #main *').contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType == 3)
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/a/g, 'z');
});
```

You could change the first bit to `$('*')`, but that is risky and probably slow, and on [this test](http://jsfiddle.net/S4SSa/6/) you can see it changes the stuff in the `<style>` that is generated by jsfiddle (so it probably will do the replace inside all `<script>`s too).

Note that the `nodeType == 3` thing is telling jQuery to return only text elements. You have to use `3` instead of the constant `Node.TEXT_NODE` because IE 7 doesn't recognize it. (surprise surprise..)

**edited** to reflect `idealmachine`'s suggestions

Comment: I would combine the `.filter` part into the function passed to `.each` using an if statement. It should be a bit faster that way because then you would not be iterating over each text node twice.

Comment: Another thing to change: `    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text().replace(/a/g, 'z'));` to `this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/a/g, 'z');`. That avoids potential problems if the text contains valid but escaped HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the body selector and take like all the children it should work... I don't really know jquery but I think you just use it wrong ... It's not normal that it changes the tags...
Use the DOM hierarchy it's the main tool of Javascript...

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna replace text of tags in an html document and you have jQuery, ***don't*** run through the entire document and replace, use jQuery's great functions for grabbing the text and innerHTML out of elements.

For example, to replace the text of all `<b>` tags on the current page you could do something like this:

```
$("b").text("Text that will replace current text");
```

Comment: But assuming that he wants to change all instances of the particular sequence he'd have to iterate through *every* DOM-node/tag.